# Items in table doesn't Scroll completely

Tags: android, android-layout

The Items in the table is not completely scrolling down even though I have taken a scroll view in the primary_layout.xml.It only scrolls till device  number .
[image: Screenshot] Please see the below code.

**TabFragment.java**

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {
public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_items = 3 ;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /**
     *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
     */
        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    /**
     *Set an Apater for the View Pager
     */
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

    /**
     * Now , this is a workaround ,
     * The setupWithViewPager dose't works without the runnable .
     * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
     */

    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
               }
    });

    return x;

}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /**
     * Return fragment with respect to Position .
     */

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
      switch (position){
          case 0 : return new PrimaryFragment();
          case 1 : return new SocialFragment();
          case 2 : return new UpdatesFragment();
      }
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return int_items;

    }

    /**
     * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
     */

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                return "Info";
            case 1 :
                return "Details";
            case 2 :
                return "Summary";
        }
            return null;
    }
}
}
```

**tab_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:background="#fff"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<View
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#616161"
android:layout_height="1px"></View>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

**primary_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/border_box"
        android:layout_margin="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/faultcategory"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Abcsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/supportlevel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Abcsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/eventstatus"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Abcsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/Servicelevel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Abcsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/user"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Abcsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/Fromeventdate"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Abcsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/ToEventDate"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Abcsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/eventNo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Abcsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/engineerName"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Abcsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/eventtypes"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Abcsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/employeeshift"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Abcsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/hostName"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Abcsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/extensionNo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Abcsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/deviceNo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Abcsd"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try adding android:fillViewport="true" in ScrollView

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't playing with status or navigation bars in your code?

Comment: @Nisarg Its not happening.

Comment: @Sufian could you please explain what you asked. Because I'm new to this. Thanks

Comment: add android:paddingBottom="48dp" to your ScrollView child 

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="48dp"
            -------------------

Comment: I think if might be because of this line `android:layout_margin="15dp"`. Try removing it. If it helps, comment back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `primary_layout`, set `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"` in `ScrollView` widget. Then it should scroll completely. After that, set bottom padding as per requirement.